# Need to match the csv and template string to generate xml

Tags: c#, .net, xml, linq

I need to generate XML based on matching the exact header values in the csvString and template string. Please advice.

Code to achieve this: (I have written below code that converts the csvString into XML and works if the csvString does not have the header column, and has only the data rows. Need to implement code that does the matching and assigns the values)

```
//Defining the final template
            string template = "Header2,Header3,Header1,Header4";
            //Defining the csvString. the 1st line is the header. each line is separated by '///'. each column is separated by ','  
            string csvString = "row11,row12,row13,row14///row21,row22,row23,row24///row31,row32,row33,row34";

            string[] split = template.Split(',');

            // Read into an array of strings.
            string[] source = csvString.Split(new string[] { "///" }, StringSplitOptions.None);
            XElement cust = new XElement("Clients",
            from str in source
            let fields = str.Split(',')
            select new XElement("Client", split.Zip(fields, (name, value) => new XElement(name, value)))
        );
```

Any help or pointer to correct direction will be useful.
Need to get it to match for example, based on this:

```
string csvString = "Header1,Header2,Header3,Header4///row11,row12,row13,row14///row21,row22,row23,row24///row31,row32,row33,row34";
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you're exactly asking for. Generating XML based on Template and Data can easily be done using XSLT. You need to be a bit more specific here to get adequate help.

Comment: Based on value of csv string headers at end of question, I need to arrange the values with respect to the order of headers in the template string.

Comment: Do you think it will be good practise to store the csv string into a data table. Then based on template string reorder the data table columns. Then convert data table to a string similar to csv string. And use the same above code to generate xml.

Comment: I know it can be done using xslt template. we have got 1000 clients each having different value of template columns. And generating xslt for each of client is big task.  So for simplicity we are using normal .net and linq

Comment: Well I am planning to convert the csv string to .net datatable and then set the columns based on the template string. Any other approach is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think for this specific case, you can implement a custom comparer for sorting header strings and sort the header array by the trailing numbers. Rows look already sorted, so they will match later.

Here is the custom string comparer:

```
public class ByNumberAtStringEnd : IComparer<string>
{
    public int Compare(string x, string y)
    {
        var num1 = Int32.Parse(System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Match(x, "\\d+$").Value);
        var num2 = Int32.Parse(System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Match(y, "\\d+$").Value);
        return num1.CompareTo(num2);
     }
}
```

Using in the code:

```
...
string template = "Header2,Header3,Header1,Header4";
//Defining the csvString. the 1st line is the header. each line is separated by '///'. each column is separated by ','  
string csvString = "row11,row12,row13,row14///row21,row22,row23,row24///row31,row32,row33,row34";
List<string> split = template.Split(',').ToList();
// --------------------------------------------- SORT THE HEADERS!!!
split.Sort(new ByNumberAtStringEnd());
// Read into an array of strings.
string[] source = csvString.Split(new string[] { "///" }, StringSplitOptions.None);
var elements = from str in source
               let fields = str.Split(',').ToList()
               select new XElement("Client", split.Zip(fields, (name, value2) => new XElement(name, value2)));

XElement cust = new XElement("Clients");
cust.Add(elements);
```

Output:

```
<Clients>
  <Client>
    <Header1>row11</Header1>
    <Header2>row12</Header2>
    <Header3>row13</Header3>
    <Header4>row14</Header4>
  </Client>
  <Client>
    <Header1>row21</Header1>
    <Header2>row22</Header2>
    <Header3>row23</Header3>
    <Header4>row24</Header4>
  </Client>
  <Client>
    <Header1>row31</Header1>
    <Header2>row32</Header2>
    <Header3>row33</Header3>
    <Header4>row34</Header4>
  </Client>
</Clients>
```

Comment: The output should have respective data under matching header. Example: header2 must have value row12. Header3 value row13. Header1 value row11.header4 value row14. The code have written gives same output as the code I have provided

Comment: The code I have written provides same output as what you have written.

Comment: Well I am planning to convert the csv string to .net datatable and then set the columns based on the template string. Any other approach is appreciated.

Comment: @helloworld: I updated the code, please have a look.

Comment: Sorry to make any misunderstanding. I am saying again. The xml order should be just like the template order. In my question there is h2 h3 h1 h4. This should be respected by the output. Your output gives h1 h2 h3 h4 order. did you get me now

Comment: I have planned to use csv string to datatable. Then use the template and reorder column of datatable using c# ordinal. Then convert the datatable back to csv. Then I can write code to convert the string to xml. Let me know if there is a better approach